# Autolayout: Scale to fill does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I am attempting to programatically add the UIView courseView to a container view (called container) that I have drawn in Interface Builder in the Storyboard.
I would like courseView to scale to fit the container. With the following code nothing shows - the courseView does not appear. What am I missing?

var courseView: UIView?

```
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    courseView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000))
    courseView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view.addSubview(courseView!)

    courseView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let courseWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView!, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: container, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let courseHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView!, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: container, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let courseViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView!, attribute: .Height , relatedBy: .Equal , toItem: courseView!, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 2.0, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraints([courseWidthConstraint, courseHeightConstraint, courseViewConstraint])

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `courseView!.layer.bounds = CGsizeMake(conatiner.layer.bounds.width, container.layer.bounds.height)` ?

Comment: Your view needs some sort of constraint to tell it what its minimum size is. Right now it just sizes it to zero width and height since those are the smallest size it can find that satisfies all your constraints

Comment: Awesome, I did not realize it sizes to the smallest possible. I thought it was the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are really trying to achieve here. But as a first suggestion, try replacing the `.LessThanOrEqual` with `.Equal` for the width constraint.

One other thing you need for your constraints to work, are some top and leading constraints to the `container`(top is just a suggestion you might want some other alignment for the height)

```
let courseLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView!, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
let courseTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView!, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
```

The aspect ration constraint for having the height half the width would be the following

```
let courseViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView!, attribute: . Width , relatedBy: .Equal , toItem: courseView!, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 2.0, constant: 0)
```

Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: I am attempting to scale the UIView courseView! with the aspect ratio of 2:1 (thus the multiplier of 2.0 in the third NSLayoutConstraint. If I set both of the first to .Equal it just fills the container view.

Comment: Do what Catalina said but also set the trailing and bottom. The bottom constraint can have a multiplier of 2. Also avoid forced unwrapping.

Comment: @Pete how should it scale? the width half the height or the other way around?

Comment: @Catalina height half of the width. Actually in my final app this value wil be variable.

Comment: Hmmm. Somehow now the container resized and both are smaller (but the aspect is now correct). What I basically want to do is keep the container size and aspect fill it with the courseView. But I am probably awful at explaining!

Comment: what are the constraints on your container?